# how fork works with logical operators

Tags: c, fork

```
main()
{
    if (fork() || (fork() && fork()))
    printf("AA\n");
    else if (!fork())
    printf("BB\n");
    else
    printf("CC\n");
}
```

I have run the following code and get the results AA AA CC BB CC BB.
While I understand how fork works, I don't understand what it does with logical operators. The teacher in our class wants us to give the answers for this homework. While I can easily run this program, I would like to know what happens exactly.
Can anyone explain or direct me to a website to what happens when using fork with logical operators.

I am pretty new to c/c++ so go easy on me. Thanks

Comment: Anyone who writes real code (as opposed to homework assignments) like this must be shot, immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fork()` returns `0` (false) to the child process, and non-zero (true) to the parent process.

You can apply logical operators to these booleans.

Remember that logical operators will short-circuit, so `0 || fork()` will not call `fork` at all.

If you read carefully through the code and think about what each `fork()` call will return, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Indeed. Probably the easiest for you would be to draw a tree, branching on each fork as it gets evaluated in the expression, with a child-branch (0) and the parent-branch (non-0).

Comment: so does !fork() reverse the values for the child and parent. the parent getting a value 0 and the child 1

Comment: You might want to change the printf statements to include the process id, to make it clearer where the output is coming from.

Comment: that would be genius, I will use the getid() function

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have used stackoverflow for a while now, just to search for answers. This is my first time asking a question and I appreciate the quick and helpful responses.

Comment: "0 || fork() will not call fork at all" should probably read "0 && fork() will not call fork at all"